# Как отправить email без учета настроек .env в laravel?

Tags: laravel

Не могу понять, как можно отправлять письма с разных электронных адресов. В моем тестовом приложении есть общий электронный адрес, а есть электронный адрес поддержки и электронный адрес для общения с администраторами. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно в разной ситуации отправлять электронные письма с разных электронных адресов, например администраторам с **"info_admin@example.com"**, общие вопросы с **"info@example.com"**, а технические вопросы с **"help@example.com"** в Laravel 8+. Использую драйвер phpMailer и в файле env указал параметры, просто с одного электронного адреса письма идут, а вот как сделать, чтобы в разных ситуациях письма шли с электронных адресов не указанных в env? Пробовал изменить параметр "from" в build(), не помогло... Может я что не так делаю, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: По-моему тут всё прекрасно и доходчиво написано: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail (искать через CTRL+F запрос `->from`)

Comment: И не `builder()`, а `build()`

Comment: У меня это не работает, я пробовал. Ответ приходит ошибка: Expected response code 354 but got code "503", with message "503 sender not yet given ".